# ApacheDS: Where is the CA certificate?

Tags: ssl, ldap, apacheds

ApacheDS auto-installs with an automatically generated certificate. For testing purposes, I'd like to just use this for now, but in order to trust it, I need the CA cert ("`/C=US/O=ASF/OU=Directory/CN=ApacheDS`") because `ldapsearch` requires the CA cert.